# Android NavigationView wrong icon position on RTL

Tags: android, android-menu, android-design-library, android-drawer

I'm using `com.android.support:design:23.1.0` and also i have `android:supportsRtl="true"` in manifest.

I'm trying to create a drawer that works fine on both **RTL** and **LTR** language.

But the default behavior in **RTL** lang is *wrong*.

how can i solve this?

tnx in advance.

[image]

[image]

activity_main2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main2.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
              android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="bottom">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main2_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camara"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/simple_switch"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools"/>
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

simple_switch.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you file a bug at [b.android.com](http://b.android.com)?